# Keras | TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nb_col'

Tags: python, keras

I am currently trying to implement this tutorial code into my own convnet.py but I get an error. [Tutorial](http://TypeError:%20__init__()%20missing%201%20required%20positional%20argument:%20'nb_col')

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "convnet.py", line 6, in <module>
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nb_col'
```

Here are the first 10 lines on which the program goes wrong:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

The code is located in the file convnet.py and I run the file like this:
    `python convnet.py`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of Keras that had the following signature:

```
Conv2D(self, nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, ...)
```

With this old version, you would define the conv layer as:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
```

You can check the version you are using with:

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

I suggest that you update your Keras.

Comment: What version is expected? I seem to have version 2.2.4 which seems to be the latest on pypi